"Invalid Login Attempt" error while passing customer id from suitelet to RESTlet
I am trying to pass customer id from suitelet to restlet. but its giving error as Invalid Login Attempt Code 401
Below is my suitelet script. Please Help!
/**

@NApiVersion 2.x

@NScriptType Suitelet
*/
define(['N/https', 'N/log', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/url'], function(https, log, serverWidget, url) {
function onRequest(context) {
if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
var form = serverWidget.createForm({
title: 'Fetch Salesforce Customer'
});
     var customerIdField = form.addField({
         id: 'custpage_customerid',
         type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
         label: 'Customer ID'
     });

     form.addSubmitButton({
         label: 'Fetch Customer'
     });

     context.response.writePage(form);
 } else {
     var customerId = context.request.parameters.custpage_customerid;
     log.debug("customerId",customerId);

     var restletUrl = url.resolveScript({
         scriptId: 'customscript_rest_ns_sf_integration',
         deploymentId: 'customdeploy_rest_ns_sf_integration'
     });

     log.debug("restletUrl",restletUrl);

     try {
         log.debug("inside try");
         var response = https.post({
             url: 'https://td2926612.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=1025&deploy=1',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
                 customerId: customerId
             })
         });
         log.debug('Response', response);

         var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
         log.debug('Restlet Response', responseBody);

         var form = serverWidget.createForm({
             title: 'Fetch Salesforce Customer'
         });

         if (response.code === 200 && responseBody.success) {
             // Display customer details
             form.addField({
                 id: 'custpage_customerdetails',
                 type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXTAREA,
                 label: 'Customer Details'
             }).defaultValue = JSON.stringify(responseBody.customerDetails, null, 4);
         } else {
             // Display error message
             form.addField({
                 id: 'custpage_errormessage',
                 type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
                 label: 'Error'
             }).defaultValue = '<p style="color: red;">Error: ' + responseBody.message + '</p>';
         }

         form.addSubmitButton({
             label: 'Fetch Another Customer'
         });

         context.response.writePage(form);
     } catch (e) {
         log.error('Error', e.message);
     }
 }

}
return {
onRequest: onRequest
};
});



Since you are using a Suitelet you can just look up the customer in the suitelet code. There doesn't appear to be a reason to call a RESTlet. Also the RESTlet would need to be called from a client script so that it has a valid authorization context. The call to use from your Suitelet code is N/https.requestRestlet
In the code supplied the body would be encoded as you have done. However you are not calling the generated RESTLet URL. Note that resolveScript will encode your params for you so generating the RESTlet url could look like:
    var customerId = context.request.parameters.custpage_customerid;

    var restletUrl = url.resolveScript({
        scriptId: 'customscript_rest_ns_sf_integration',
        deploymentId: 'customdeploy_rest_ns_sf_integration',
        params: {
             custparam_id: customerId // substitute what your RESTlet expects for custparam_id
        }
    });

    var response = https.get({
             url: restletUrl 
    }); //GET illustrates no need for a single param POST body but your original POST would work. 


